# Incorrect name attached to question on home page

Tags: support

I posted [How to quickly batch save Bitmaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024383/how-to-quickly-batch-save-bitmaps) then went to the home page to look at other questions while I waited for answers. I noticed my question on the home page, and it has not my username attached to it (it is Abion47). I clicked on the link several times, and it links properly to my question; I refreshed the page as well, but it keeps showing alexm. I don't know who this user is, but he hasn't voted, answered, commented, or (to my knowledge) even viewed my question.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Someone edited so his name shows up. No issue.

Comment: So he edited my post, or his name just randomly appears whenever anyone edits? Also, my post doesn't mention that anyone edited it, neither does alexm's activity page...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The home page shows the user with the last recorded activity on a post.  [alexm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/898142/alexm) had answered your question but then immediately deleted the answer.  Apparently, since deleted posts aren't really deleted but just hidden, that still counts as the last activity.

Comment: Was thinking about that, but had no way to confirm it. That crazy diamond ;)

Comment: That makes sense in an annoying sort of way.

Comment: Editing deleted posts results in this behavior as well